# post meta parameter in post custom-post-type endpoint with restapi

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, rest-api

I'm trying to create a new custom post via the native Wordpress REST API

POST /wp-json/wp/v2/CUSTOMPOST

at the moment I used the wp-rest-api-controller plugin to activate the endpoints

the custom post is created

but the "meta" parameter is ignored

1st question
??? what is the structure of the "meta" parameter that has to be passed in the request ???

"meta": {"META_KEY": "META_VALUE"}

or

"meta": {"key": "META_KEY", "value": "META_VALUE"}

example of my request

POST /wp-json/wp/v2/CUSTOMPOST

{"slug": "slugnewpost14", "title": "titlenewpost14", "status": "publish", "content": "contentnewpost", "meta": {"key": "coordinates", "value": "37:12"}}

the custom post is created but the "meta" parameter is ignored

///////////////////////////////////////

2nd question

http://MYDOMAIN/wp-json/

```
    {

  "name": "delisasudwpflag1",

  "namespaces": [

    "wp/v2"

  ],

  "routes": {

    . . .
    . . .
    . . .

    "/wp/v2/CUSTOMPOST": {

      "namespace": "wp/v2",

      "endpoints": [

        {

          "methods": [

            "POST"

          ],

          "args": {

            "date": {

            "date_gmt": {

            "slug": {

            "status": {

            . . . 
            . . . 
            . . . 



        ??? there is no "meta" parameter, should there be if it was correctly registered ???
```